# Can Facebook app name be translated so it can be available in search results for different languages?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I wandered if it is possible to have one Facebook application but to translate it in other languages so application name could be searched via Facebook search bar on many different languages.

For example, if i want to make app called "Warm Spring", can i translate it in my developers  dashboard so it could be available in search results if some people from Germany searches for "Warm Fruhling"?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

According to [Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/internationalization/#prepare) your app name can be translated . Just follow the steps indicated in the link.

Comment: Hello Darvex, yes i read that but that is about translating application content. I would like to know if i translate application name to another language will it be available in search box under that translated name.

Comment: I'm afraid i've got no information on that. I suspect that it would be available, otherwise it just defeats the purpose of translating. But i suggest you try it out yourself.